# How could we change our IP while executing POST in HttpClient on Apache Library?

Tags: java, ip, httpclient, ip-address

I'm trying to mimicing a form-post by using this HttpClient library.
and it seems okay without any problem.

Only 1 things matter. 
Is there any way to change the IP Address of the sender(us)...
by using this library? I didn't found the Doc mentioning that one.

I'm just thinking that ... Would it be possible if I just used 1 pc and 1 internet connection and executing the form-post and changing my own IP Address without interrupting the connection via this library?

correct me if i'm wrong.please.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  HttpClient doesn't use IP address.  Once the underlying TCP connection is established, the server sees the IP address of the requesting client.  Then HTTP communication is taking place over that TCP pipe.

Comment: huhuhu... ya i thought just by changing the header is enough.
but i got answers from others mentioning it is not possible. unless changing the ip address from JVM?? What?? Neverheard. :(

Comment: The answer to your question is "this is not possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the IP Address of the sender(us)... by using this library?

It is not possible from pure Java.

In fact, it is only possible if you can change the machine's IP address ... or use some kind of OS provided "raw" network facility that allows you to fake/spoof the IP address in transmitted network packets.

I'd advise you to not try this.  Think of a different approach to whatever it is that you are trying to achieve.